# Finding Location of a Device with GPS feature

Tags: java, javascript, html

Is it possible to find the location of a device without using internet if a button is clicked on the website which uses Geo Location API? Is it possible to get the location if the device has GPS but no internet connection?

Comment: If you're clicking a button on a website, doesn't that imply you're using the Internet?

Comment: I meant i have a website that I am running on localhost.... so i want to add this functionality to it and find the location of a place via a device which will be using this website.... so if that device is not connected to internet i.e. it is in offline mode but still has GPS in it will it be able to get the location....